# In my code why date of month are different in Java Date or Calendar?

Tags: java, date, calendar

Here is my code.

```
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Calender: "+calendar);
    System.out.println("Calender Date: "+calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("Date: "+new Date().getDate());
```

Output:

[image]

In red box Calendar show `DAY_OF_MONTH=14`, but `calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` show `5`.

Comment: Thanks to All for quick reply. now i get the reason..

Comment: Then you should probably mark an answer as accepted so that people know you've solved it.

Comment: @Duncan all answer are same its so how can i accept only one. +1 for all

Comment: I dunno. Pick the guy with the lowest rep to give him/her a boost? Roll a dice? Pick your favourite username? :-). It's not critical you do this, so don't worry about it if you don't want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH) is a [constant value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), which points at the day of the month field.

To get the actual value, you'd need to call:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Answer (score 4):

what you are printing here

```
System.out.println("Calender Date: "+calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

is the value of the constant DAY_OF_MONTH

The correct way to get the value is `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

Answer (score 3):

`calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` is only a key. The DAY_OF_MONTH from `Calendar` you get via `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because you are accessing the constant field value for `DAY_OF_MONTH` and not the actual day of month.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` instead. You are currently printing out a constant in the Calendar class used to get the field's value in a given instance.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println("Calender Date: "+calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

You just get the constant field value for DAY_OF_MONTH  from Calendar,

it's not the actual day ,so you get two different results,

if you want to get the actual day of month,you can do this:

calendar.get(**Calendar**.DAY_OF_MONTH)